# Support all orientation in AVCaptureSession

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I have a simple camera app, and I want it to rotate the camera view when I rotate the iPhone.

Currently, I setup `AVCaptureSession` like that

```
func setupCaptureSession(camera: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .front) {
    
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: camera) else {
        fatalError("Error getting AVCaptureDevice.")
    }
    

    guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else {
        fatalError("Error getting AVCaptureDeviceInput")
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.session = AVCaptureSession()
        self.session?.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
        self.session?.addInput(input)
        
        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: .main)
        
        self.session?.addOutput(output)
        output.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        self.session?.startRunning()
    }
}
```

Currently it supports `portrait` and if I remove `output.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .portrait` it will be support only landscape. I want it to support all the origination and camera view rotate when I rotate the phone. Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `orientationDidChangeNotification` to detect when the device is rotating. Add it in the `viewDidLoad`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and

```
@objc private func deviceOrientationDidChange() {
    
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .portrait:
        self.videoDataOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        self.videoDataOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
    case .landscapeLeft:
        self.videoDataOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
    case .landscapeRight:
        self.videoDataOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
    default: break
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to detect the device's orientation. We should rather listen to the interface's orientation.